# How to import component during the runtime

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I started using Vue JS 3 and I would like to know if I can and its possible to import component ( modals )   during the runtime   I tried that but didn't work

```
watch:{
        modal:{
            handler(newModal){
                App.component('modal', () => import(newModal))
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: I gather you are using Options API not Composition API? Perhaps you want to research "lazy loading component in vue 3" - there's a wealth of info when you do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read about "Async Components" on the official [Vue 3 documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/async.html#loading-and-error-states).

Basically, you can register a component as asynchronous, and it will lazyload itself when it tries to render the first time.

#### Simple `defineAsyncComponent`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <Modal v-if="open" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {
    MySyncComponent,
    Modal: defineAsyncComponent(() => import('./Modal.vue'))
  }
}
</script>
```

#### Using `<script setup>`:

```html
<script setup>
const Modal = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('./Modal.vue'))
</script>
```

#### Specifying custom lazyloading options:

```js
const Modal = defineAsyncComponent({
  loader: () => import('./Modal.vue'),
  loadingComponent: ProgressSpinner,
  delay: 150, // waits 150ms before showing the loading spinner
  errorComponent: ErrorComponent,
  timeout: 2000 // if not loaded before 2s, will show error
})
```

#### Using `<Suspense>` wrapper component:

With the `Suspense` component, all child component will be treated as asynchronous by default. They will be in their own chunk of code.

```html
<Suspense>
  <Modal v-if="open"> <!-- Loading as asynchronous -->
  <template #fallback>
    Loading...
  </template>
</Suspense>
```

Comment: what if I want to open another modal ?

Comment: Well the component would be already pre-loaded and you can use it like any other component. You can have 10 Modal in your component, it won't change anything :)